# TagCloud npm package not working in Next js Website after Deploying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, tag-cloud

I am using TagCloud npm package to create 3d word sphere in Next js. It is working fine on development server but not working after Deploying. Website is hosted but 3d word sphere is not showing  up.[here is working TagCloud[This is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSjsK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpiMQ.png)

and also it not showing any error in terminal or console

I tried everything but its not working.
I want TagCloud to also word on production environment